# How can I extract the strings declared inside the java which went into a jar file

Tags: java, jar, decompiler

Is there a equivalent to the Unix `strings` command for jar files?

To give an example, if I have this Java file:

```
public class Foo {
    String foo = "I\'m so meta even this acronym";
}
```

compiled and placed in bar.jar

I will, ideally, like to run some command on bar.jar which will send the string "I'm so meta" to standard output so I can grep for it.

The problem I am trying to solve is, I'm getting an error message in my Java program, and I will like to know which jar file its coming from.

Comment: You can use javap to decode a specific class in a jar.

Comment: A jar file is only an archive. You can extract the class-files out of the jar and use `strings` on it.

Comment: @benhsu - I assume there is no stack trace with your error message. How is the exception logged? To console or via a library like Log4J?

Comment: @Perception, correct, the app just logs an error message. I need to track down which jar its coming from before I can add more meaningful logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:
`unzip -p your.jar |strings| grep 'your string'`

To search through multiple JAR files in the directory use:
`unzip -p \*.jar |strings| grep 'your string'`

Comment: It's probably worth explaining what that does.

Answer (score 2):

Jars are just zip files so that is a good starting point.

```
unzip -p myfile.jar | grep "Error message"
```

seems to work, however unzip may print control characters so it could mess up your current console. You would be better to actually unzip the files into a directory and run strings on it.  Probably something like this would work

```
for file in `ls *.jar`
do
  echo $file
  unzip -ol $file | awk '{ print $4 }' > extracted && cat extracted | xargs strings | grep "ERROR MESSAGE" && cat extracted | xargs rm -rf
done
```

I bet there is a more efficient way of doing that, some shell script guru will clean this up for me I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

If your error message is thrown exception I'd suggest you to examine the stacktrace and get the class and method that throws exception. Then decompile the class using jad (java decompiler) and see where the message arrives from.

Answer (score -2):

you can try a "nohup" command in Unix. here all exceptions and standard output will be append into a file

The command is

```
nohup java -jar bar.jar > bar.out &
```

now see the file bar.out for the error messages in your jar execution.